# SQL-SERVER: Parsear una cadena con delimitadores para campos y filas obteniendo una tabla

Tags: sql, stored-procedure, sql-server-2008

De una cadena que tiene delimitadores de campo y de filas debo extraer los datos como filas y columnas para insertarlos en una tabla. Para realizar la partición de la cadena, debido a que mi versión de motor de base de datos es 2008, implementé la siguiente función:

```
--SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString]('2~125~78000000~|1~14~45285000~|5~125~68352200~|')
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
    ( 
            @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
            @delimiter CHAR(1) 
    ) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
        DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
        SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
        WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
            IF @end = 0  
                SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1
            INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
            VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
            SET @start = @end + 1 
            SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
        END 
        RETURN 
END
```

la cual me resuelve la segmentación de las cadenas que contienen la información de cada fila separadas por el caracter '|'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no el de campos '~'. Alguien podría ayudar para ver como puedo hacer este proceso?. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ya estas trayendo uno.. que te impide volver a hacer lo mismo por cada fila?

Answer (score 0):

Si su motor de base de datos es Sql-Server 2008 (como esta etiquetado en la pregunta) hay que hacerle una modificación a su table-valued-function `fnSplitString` agregándole una columna que indique en que posición de la cadena se encuentra la parte que se extrajo. A continuación la funcion modificada para dicho efecto:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] ( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX), position int) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT , @position int = 1
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1
        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata, position)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start),@position) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
        set @position = @position + 1
    END 
    RETURN 
END
go
```

Con dicha funcion compilada ya se puede realizar la siguiente consulta utilizando `CTE` y `cross apply` para obtener un conjunto de filas y columnas de la cadena de prueba

```
DECLARE @TestString varchar(max) = '2~125~78000000~|1~14~45285000~|5~125~68352200~|'

;with
 c1 as (SELECT a.position as nfila, a.splitdata
          FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString](@TestString,'|') as a)
,c2 as (select c1.nfila, b.splitdata, b.position
          from c1
               cross apply (select *
                              from [dbo].[fnSplitString](c1.splitdata,'~')) as b )
,c3 as (select c1.nfila
              ,(select c2.splitdata from c2 where c2.nfila = c1.nfila and c2.position=1) as field_1
              ,(select c2.splitdata from c2 where c2.nfila = c1.nfila and c2.position=2) as field_2
              ,(select c2.splitdata from c2 where c2.nfila = c1.nfila and c2.position=3) as field_3               
          from c1 )
select c3.field_1, c3.field_2, c3.field_3
  from c3
 order by nfila
```

Si el motor de base de datos tiene compatibilidad superior a 130 puede utilizar la función nativa `STRING_SPLIT` para escribir una versión modificada de `fnSplitString` así:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] ( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX), position int) 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @output (splitdata, position)
    select a.[value], ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 0)) as position
      from string_split(@string, @delimiter) as a
     where a.[value]<>''
    RETURN 
END
go
```

Comment: Usar ROW_NUMBER() con STRING_SPLIT no es recomendable porque el orden de los valores no está garantizado. Ya hay una corrección a la función que permite añadir una columna con el orden de los valores, pero solo está disponible en  los productos SQL de Azure y SQL Server 2022.